# Using Facebook Graph api to post content to Fan pages as admin

Tags: facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post content to my facebook fan pages by making a post request to the graph api end points with the access_token of the corresponding fan page . 
The content gets posted successfully to the page and I am able to see it from the admin account on facebook . 
The problem is that is that no one else is able to see the content posted from the script except the admin . Is there a restriction to post content publicly to Fb Fan pages using a script (a facebook app ) ? Because , I have been using a script to post to Facebook GROUPS , which is working perfect . But the problem is with the pages .

PS: The script is written in JS in node.js and yes I have all the required permissions to manage the content .

Comment: Have you got the post visibility set correctly on your fanpage? https://www.facebook.com/help/www/356113237741414

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn  ,the posts and page both are visible to everyone possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction that i can think of, my guess is that your app is in sandbox mode? (see "Status & Review" settings). It is off for new apps, and you need to enter a support email in the settings to be able to go live with the app.

Btw, please include the relevant code where you actually post to the page, be as detailed as possible in your description.